# Deselect Checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to deselect the checkboxes that are in disabled state using JQuery

I used live type with 'change' event in Jquery. The following code deselects all checkboxes. But I need only for disabled checkboxes.

```
$('.checkboxGroups').removeAttr('checked').trigger('change');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
$(".checkboxGroups:disabled")
```

See more about [:disabled Selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $(".checkboxGroups:disabled").prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS `:disabled` pseudo-selector:

```
$('.checkboxGroups:disabled').removeAttr('checked').trigger('change');
```

...though given the plurality of the classname -- is '.checkboxGroups' the *container*?

If so, then:

```
$('.checkboxGroups input:disabled').removeAttr('checked').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to find the disable checkboxes using the below statement then perform your opearation.

```
$('.checkboxGroups').attr('disabled', true)
```